# Ruby - how to create a list from a number of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of hashes. I would want to put them into a list where i could access each data point. My question is would i use another hash and assign keys to the data points or store them into an array?

```
data_point_a = {:label => "cat", :features => [0.25,0.1,5]}
data_point_b = {:label => "dog", :features => [0.3,0.14,7]}
data_point_c = {:label => "dog", :features => [0.2,0.17,6]}
data_point_d = {:label => "dog", :features => [0.4,0.12,8]}
data_point_e = {:label => "cat", :features => [0.1,0.11,3]}
data_point_f = {:label => "unknown", :features => [0.8,0.3,4]}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? Yes, you could make an array like `[data_point_a, …]` or a hash like `{ data_point_a: data_point_a, … }`. Whether one or the other (or some third thing) would be suitable for you is impossible to say without knowing more. What do you want to achieve? Are there any performance constraints? Etc.

Comment: @HenrikN  I forgot to ask if whether it would be ideal to use an array or hash for the list if i were going to use it with an iterator inside another function